# Why is there an error regarding handles with labels in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, handle

I am trying to plot from a .txt file and I am getting an error when executing regarding the legend. I'm not sure what the error here is. Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
plt.close('all')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# read data
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
DATA_PATH = '/home/public/WS1819_Ex3/experiments/exercise_02/Absorption.txt'
data = np.genfromtxt(DATA_PATH, skip_header=1)
x, y1, y2, y3 = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3]

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# prepare canvas
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel('Abstand [cm]')
ax.set_ylabel(u'Intensität [V]')
ax.set_title(u'Absorption von Licht in Wasser')
# set logarithmic y-scale
ax.set_yscale('log')
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# plot data
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.show()

ax.legend()
fig.savefig('Absorption.pdf')
```

And here is the output:

```
OUTPUT:

No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: `ax.legend()` <- What are you trying to do here?

Comment: To create a legend you need to give a label to an artist on the plot. i.e. using `label=` argument in `plt.plot`

Comment: To clarify the above comment: `plt.plot(x, y1 , label='something')`.

Comment: As a note - This warning no longer appears in matploltib version 2.1 and above

Comment: Thanks. I added what DavidG and 9769953 said and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
# plot data
p1 = plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.legend((p1[0]), (header[0]), fontsize=12, ncol=1, framealpha=0, fancybox=True)
```